Can evm make an EOA transaction during another transaction?
I want to deploy a smart contract that would do something like this:

transfer eth from the contract to account A
make a transaction to another smart contract from account A(given the nonce and the private key)

I know I can sign the transaction using A's key and not publish it yet, but can I then pass it to my contract and execute it as part of my transaction 1)?
Can evm do it? Or is there any other workaround to achieve this?
My goal is to combine these two transactions together one after the other in the same block

A contract cannot access another account's funds.
There several possible solutions. One is to use contract as user wallet. The main contract will call the user wallet with the request, the user wallet then validates and transfer the funds.
